"They hunkered down in their hotel room." VS "They were hunkered down in their hotel room."
I heard this on TV about the hurricane:

They were hunkered down in their hotel room, where they have been moved to a higher floor.

This the first time I have heard the verb "to hunker down". I looked it up and learn the meaning and checked the example sentences. However, what caught my attention is that it seems to have both active and passive meaning without changing anything. You can say "They were hunkered down...." OR "They hunkered down.....", which seem to mean the same.
So in place of the sentence above, I seem to be able to say:

"They hunkered down in their hotel room......"

Am I right in my thinking?

The literal meaning of hunker down is to squat, so 'to be hunkered down' is 'to be in a squatting position'.

@Kate Bunting, If it means "to squat", then the sentence in the passive structure "They were hunkered down" would mean "Somebody hunkered them down", wouldn't it?

I'm afraid not, in this case. We can use participles to indicate position - "He was crouched down' - "He was stretched out". There has been discussion on these forums as to whether it's legitimate to say "He was sat there" - it's commonly used nowadays, although I was always taught to use sitting.

@Yunus  They could have hunkered themselves down. Reflexive. Compare: They were seated.

Very very good points. Never thought about that, and this type of "seemingly passive" structure was never taught in lessons at school.

One can be hunkered down (adjectival) OR one can hunker down. The squat reference in these cases has been lost in terms of meaning.

Which form to use really depends on whether you're describing a scene or an action/attitude.

The advisors were hunkered down in a hotel room, discussing the politician's next move.

They're sequestered.

He was going to ask for a raise that day but decided to hunker down until his boss was in a better mood.

He's biding his time, lying low for the time being.

With the blizzard all flights had been cancelled, so they hunkered down in the airport lounge.

They've "parked their butts"  in the lounge.

The predominant usage is in the active voice.  The NOUN in the NOUN hunkered down graph ensures this is in the active voice.
The example sentences I found in major dictionaries are also in the active voice.
Hence the OP’s suggestion is fine:

They hunkered down in their hotel room ...

